# Hough transform parallelized (on CPU or using GPU computation) on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing, gpu, hough-transform

I am doing image analysis on images of droplets in an emulsion. They appears as dark (black) *rings* on a rather homogeneous light grey background.
To detect them I use `imfindcircles` Matlab function. Unfortunately I have many images to post-treat. Does anyone happen to know if there is a parallel function that would speed up the process? Is there a parallel version of this circular Hough transform?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should process the images in parallel. Start different MATLAB sessions, have each process a subset of images. That is always the most efficient form of parallelization.

Comment: I was actually doing this so far, but I have many movies (images sequences) to compute, I was hence looking for a parallel way or another method using the GPU...?

Comment: If you have e.g. 8 cores, running the same algorithm on 8 different sets of data simultaneously is more efficient than running a parallelized version of the algorithm on one data set across the 8 cores. Because there is always some sort of penalty for parallelization. The one time when this is not true is when the problem is a limitation in the data access, then your processor is waiting for data from disk rather than computing. A GPU version of the algorithm might help you, since you then can use a different resource. That depends on your code, I'm sure it's more than just `imfindcircles`.

Comment: mayb this helps: https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/12/10/image-processing-with-a-gpu/

Comment: @CrisLuengo the thing is: imfincircles does not run on a gpuArray...